# How can I get a Django view to look up a model's self attribute

Tags: python, django

I'm putting together a website that includes a directory of people in an organization. In the models a person has a name attribute, which is then used to auto-create a slug for a URL as shown below, which essentially just squishes their name into something like "FirstnameLastname".

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Name')
...

    def slug(self):
        slg = self.name.replace(",", "")
        slg = slg.replace(".", "")
        slg = slg.replace("-", "")
        return slg.replace(" ", "")
```

In my templates, links to particular people can use the syntax "Member.slug" correctly to link to what should be the URL of their webpage, like "www.website.com/People/FirstnameLastname/".

In my urls.py file, the line setting up the URL reads as such:

```
url(r'^people/(?P<member_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.person, name='person')
```

This url setup has worked for me previously. I'm not well versed in regex, but I don't think this should be causing problems.

My view for a person's page is below:

```
from app.models import Member

def person(request, member_slug):
    pk_match=0
    member_list = Member.objects.all()
    for member_check in member_list:
        if member_check.slug==member_slug:
            pk_match=member_check.pk
            break
    member = get_object_or_404(Member, pk=pk_match)
    return render(request, "app/person.html", {'member': member})
```

The view won't work for me. The Django debugging window tells me that there is no match for the model. For one reason or another, it seems that it can't reference the Member.slug attribute from the view. If I manually set the pk to a valid number then it will load the page for that user, so the error is definitely within the lookup scheme I have. Is there a way to do this so that website URLs are automatically made from the name of the person, yet have it look up that individual correctly in the view?

Comment: A good way to debug this would be to print/log statements to the loop, e.g. `print(member_check.slug)`. Then you would spot that `member_check.slug` is not what you expected it to be.

Comment: Side note - Something to consider, and maybe your slug method isn't full or complete for this example, but I would recommend making the slugs unique in the case of two people with the same name. For instance, rather than having two 'John Doe's with the slug 'John-Doe' (you'll run into a multiple objects error with a get lookup), the first could be 'John-Doe' and the second could be 'John-Doe-1', etc. Just food for thought!

Comment: also note that Django provides a `SlugField` already https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

Comment: by not having the slug saved as a field on the model you have created a potential problem... you now have to loop over all the `Member` records in your view to see if the slug matches. what happens when you have 1000 members, or 10000, or a million?  this is not going to scale well

Answer (score 3):

`Member.slug()` is a method, so you need to call it, otherwise the comparison will always be `False`.

```
member_check.slug() == member_slug
```

Or you can change it to a property, then `member_check.slug == member_slug` will work.

```
@property
def slug(self):
    slg = self.name.replace(",", "")
    slg = slg.replace(".", "")
    slg = slg.replace("-", "")
    return slg.replace(" ", "")
```